# List of acitivies for sharing is empty with IOS10

Tags: ios, share, swift3, ios10, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have some problem with sharing with SO iOS10.
I wrote this code to choose a activity and share a link

```
@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let objectsToShare = ["Shared by: xxxxxx**strong text**", url]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    //New Excluded Activities Code
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList]

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone {
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
        let popup: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityVC)
        popup.present(from: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 4, width: 0, height: 0), in: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.any, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In previous version a new viewcontroller was opened to choose which activity use to share, but now I see this

[No activity is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2g5a.png)
Does noone have this problem?

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird.... The problem solved automatically.
All works now without any patch 
My iPhone updated to iOS 10.0.2, maybe this version solved the issue